# From which mysql variable does mysql know the IP of the master node in a group replication environment?

Tags: mysql

When I "start group_replication" command how does mysql know which IP to use to connect to the master node?

I ask because when running

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_USER='repl', 
       MASTER_PASSWORD='password' 
FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery';
```

I do not define a MASTER_HOST.

Does it get the master host/ip from one of the IPs in "loose-group_replication_group_seeds" ?

Comment: `SELECT member_host FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE member_role = 'PRIMARY';` or `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'group_replication_primary_member';`. See [Group Replication Settings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-configuring-instances.html#group-replication-configure-plugin), `group_replication_group_seeds` usage description.

Comment: I am setting up MASTER-to-MASTER tho

Comment: Multi-primary mode? In multi-primary mode (`group_replication_single_primary_mode=OFF`) no member has a special role.

Comment: It will not connect with a timeout
```
2019-11-01T06:32:22.550273Z 16 [System] [MY-010597] [Repl] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'.
Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-11-01T06:33:22.584319Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-011640] [Repl] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'

Comment: I don't understand at all. Replication may be either master-slave or group, not both.

Comment: I am trying to setup multi primary with (group_replication_single_primary_mode=OFF) not master-slave. Do I just run the "change master" command on the first node in group?

Comment: it seems you use wrong steps order... `group_replication` plugin must be unloaded when you set user to group replication channel, AFAIR. I.e. you create user, set it to channel, (install and) load plugin, start 1st node, start another nodes.